# I want to store my arr[] value into power of 2.. But I got some output not really like what I really want

Tags: c++

I want to convert a number into binary and store those binary value:
Example:
11 is  1011.. so I want to store those 2^3, 2^1, 2^1 numbers, so I can use those number. but my code doesn't store them right correctly. I got 8 4 2 for that instead of 8 2 1

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

int num, arr[64];
int binary[10000];
cin >> num;

int expmax;
expmax = log2(num);
cout << expmax << endl;

int b = expmax;

int i = 0, r;
while (num != 0)
{
    r = num % 2;
    arr[i++] = r;
    num /= 2;
}
for (int m = 0; m <= expmax ; m++)
{
    cout << "array " << arr[m]  << endl;
}
cout << endl;
int n = 0;
for (n++; n <= expmax; expmax--)
{ 
    if (arr[n] = 1)
    {
        binary[n] = pow(2, expmax);
        cout << binary[n] << endl;
    }

    else 
    {
        binary[n] = pow(2, expmax)*0;
        cout << binary[n] << endl;
    }

}
cout << endl;
for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    cout << arr[j];

}
cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

```
if (arr[n] = 1)
```

*sets* `arr[n]` to 1 and is *always* true (it evaluates to 1).

You want:

```
if (arr[n] == 1)
```

which is only true if `arr[n]` *equals* 1.

You are also bumping `n` to 1 at the start of the loop with:

```
int n = 0;
for (n++; n <= expmax; expmax--)
      ^^
```

Use this instead:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= expmax; ++n)
```